# What is the use of declare with option -t

Tags: bash, shell-script, function, trap

If you call the command `help declare`. You will see the following information:

```
-t NAME :  to make NAMEs have the `trace' attribute
```

Is there any example that demonstrates the use of this option. I thought that this plays the same role as that of the command `set -o functrace` except that it only applies to the arguments instead of all functions.

The motivation of this question is that I want a function foo to inherits a trap. So I tried `declare -t foo` but it did not work.

I can certainly use `set -o functrace` to make all functions to inherit a trap, but there are circumstances when I want only one or two functions to inherit a trap.

Here is the script:

```
function foo {
    var=1
    var=2
    var=3
}

declare -t foo

var=0

trap 'echo var is $var' DEBUG
    foo
trap - DEBUG    # turn off the DEBUG trap
```

Here is the output of the script:

```
var is 0
var is 3
```

I was expecting to get something like:

```
var is 0
var is 1
var is 2
var is 3
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`declare -t foo` sets the trace attribute on the *variable* `foo` (which has no special effect anyway). You need to use `-f` to set it on the function:

```
declare -ft foo
```

With your script modified to use `-f`, I get the following output (explanation in comments):

```
var is 0 # foo called
var is 0 # before the first command in function is run
var is 0 # var=1
var is 1 # var=2
var is 2 # var=3
var is 3 # trap ...
```

Comment: `-t` has no special meaning for variables, so I wonder why `-t` does not imply `-f`?

Comment: @jarno when it was added, [way back in bash-2.05b-alpha1](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2002-07/msg00005.html), it said "Currently has no effect on variables." I suppose they wanted to have the option of having it do something for variables in the future, but nothing was ever added for variables.